# How to use std::bitset count() with constexpr in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to use `std::bitset<64>(n).count()` in constexpr functions but bitset::count is not constexpr. I thought I could do something like the following:

```
#include <bitset>

inline constexpr size_t bit_count(uint64_t v) noexcept
{
  if constexpr(true) {
    size_t n = 0;
    while (v) {
      v &= v - 1; // clear right-most 1-bit
      ++n;
    }
    return n;
  }

  return std::bitset<64>(v).count();
}

static_assert(bit_count(42) == 3);

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    return bit_count(argc);
}
```

The main point is that we always want to use bitset::count at runtime, and the while loop alternative implementation is only for compile time.

But in the example above, bit_count(argc) is not a constexpr expression and so the while loop implementation gets used at runtime. (See https://godbolt.org/z/W7oj7jnc9)

How do we force bitset::count to be used at runtime while still allowing bit_count to be used in static_assert?

Comment: why do you want to do that? In C++20 you can just use [std::popcount](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount)

Comment: Yes, std::popcount is what I actually want, though it is not the answer to my question strictly speaking. `std::is_constant_evaluated` is, or eventually `if consteval`. Thank you though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`std::is_constant_evaluated()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated).  That would give you

```
inline constexpr size_t bit_count(uint64_t v) noexcept
{
  if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
    size_t n = 0;
    while (v) {
      v &= v - 1; // clear right-most 1-bit
      ++n;
    }
    return n;
  }

  return std::bitset<64>(v).count();
}
```

And now the `if` only runs when you are in a constant expression and you use `std::bitset::count` when not.

---

One thing you do not want to do though is to use

```
if constexpr(std::is_constant_evaluated())
```

Since `if constexpr` is a constant expression, `std::is_constant_evaluated()` would always be true, and you would always enter the body of the if statement, which is not what you want.

Comment: You can even use `if constexpr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 If you are saying you could use `if constexpr(std::is_constant_evaluated())`, then you can, but it is a bug since `if constexpr(std::is_constant_evaluated())` will always be true.

Comment: Indeed, I kept the comment as that mistake might be common.

Comment: @Jarod42 I added it into the answer so it's more visible and permanent.

Answer (score 2):

In future C++23, you might do

```
constexpr size_t bit_count(uint64_t v) noexcept
{
    if consteval {
        size_t n = 0;
        while (v) {
           v &= v - 1; // clear right-most 1-bit
        ++n;
        }
        return n;
    } else {
        return std::bitset<64>(v).count();
    }
}
```